# A division algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies $S^{n-1}$ is parallelizable.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm in the final stages of proving the desired proposition, but I'm having difficulties showing that some vector fields are smooth. I'm given next to nothing about the division algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is where much of the difficulty for me lies. All we have is that multiplication is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear. We do not have that the algebra is commutative, associative, or has $1$.

My argument is as follows. Express $S^{n-1} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| = 1\}$. For all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the map $f_x (a) = \frac{x \cdot a}{||x \cdot a||}$ is a diffeomorphism $S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$. Fix $e = (1,0,\dots,0) \in S^{n-1}$, and choose a basis $\{\xi_{i,e} : i = 1, \dots, n\}$ of $T_eS^{n-1}$. For each $y \in S^{n-1}$, let $y'$ be the unique solution to the equation $y' \cdot e = y$. Then $T_ef_{y'} = Tf_{y'}|_{TeS^{n-1}}$ induces a linear isomorphism $T_eS^{n-1} \to T_{f_{y'}(e)}S^{n-1} = T_yS^{n-1}$ and thus maps $\{\xi_{i,e}\}$ to a basis of $T_yS^{n-1}$. Define the vector field $\xi_i: M \to TM$ by $\xi_i(a) = \xi_{i,a} = T_ef_{a'}(\xi_{i,e})$. It's clear that the $\xi_i$'s satisfy the requirements for being an $n$-frame, and now all I need to do is show that each $\xi_i$ is smooth. Since $\xi_i$ is defined somewhat indirectly, and relies on solving the equation $a' \cdot e = a$, I don't know if the solutions vary smoothly as $a$ varies smoothly (in coordinates).